# Why are there more irrational numbers in the solutions of cube roots than in the square roots?

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

I have been programming in SML and while implementing the function for natural square roots and natural cubic roots, I noticed that (real) cube roots somehow seem to have "more" irrational numbers as solutions in a given interval for x than in the (real) square roots.

So, for instance. Given an input interval [0,20] for x we find more irrational cube roots   than we can find irrational square roots in the same interval. I first thought that it might have been a coincidence, so I repeatedly widened the interval for x and still noticed that cube roots have more irrational numbers as solutions than square roots. (If I could, I would try to prove it inductively, but I don't quite yet have a good sense of proof techniques, so I can only rely on trial here)

I was wondering if there is a sufficient explanation on why this is the case. I tried wrapping my head around it, but couldn't really find a solution. My first thought (although heuristic) was that the difficulty of finding a perfect cube is much higher than finding a perfect square.

Comment: I am not sure if I am understanding your question.  So, my response may not be on point.  When examining (for example) $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ you have that $$[(n+1)^3 - n^3] > [(n+1)^2 - n^2].$$  Then, all of the positive integers in the range $~[(n+1)^3 - n^3]~$ **exclusive,** will have irrational cube roots, and all of the numbers in the range $~[(n+1)^2 - n^2]~$ **exclusive,** will have irrational square roots.

Comment: Are you asking why there are, in a given range, less integers of the form $n^3$ than  integers of the form $n^2$?

Comment: Do you mean "cube roots," which is solutions to $x^3=a,$ or "cubic roots," which would be roots of any cubic equation: $x^3+bx^2+cx+d=0?$ Because you compare cubic roots to square roots, which is weirdly mixing types.

Comment: @MartinR I also wondered about that.  My previous comment, which may be a misinterpretation of what the original poster is asking, made that assumption.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oh, yes, I actually meant "cube roots". In Germany we call them "Kubikwurzeln" so that might be why I incorrectly called it "cubic roots". Sorry about that.

Comment: @user2661923 See my comment above

Comment: So you are really asking for $x$ rational in $[0,20],$ why does it seem more common for $\sqrt x$ to be rational than $\sqrt[3]{x}$ rational? Technically, both sets are infinite and countable, hence the same size, and you don't have  you can't use a probability measure on the set of $x$ values which is uniform. So if you are picking $x$ randomly, you have to pick a probability measure on an infinite countable set. That said, every rational which is a cube root of some rational in $[0,20]$ is also a square root of some rational in $[0,20],$ but not visa versa.

Comment: When you say "more" irrational square roots than irrational cube roots in $[0,20],$ how many square roots are we talking about? $380$? Or more, as in the previous comment?